# when onBackPress happens in fragments app will close

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I made some fragments and a nav_Graph and using setOnClickListener on some button and actions from nav_Graph to move between the fragments but when I press the back button it will close the app
how can I fix that ?

**the nav_graph**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_register_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/introdcutionFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/introdcutionFragment"
        android:name="com.example.go.ui.fragment.IntrodcutionFragment"
        android:label="IntrodcutionFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_introdcution">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_introdcutionFragment_to_accountOptionsFragment"
            app:destination="@id/accountOptionsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="com.example.go.ui.fragment.LoginFragment"
        android:label="LoginFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_loginFragment_to_registerFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/accountOptionsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/registerFragment"
        android:name="com.example.go.ui.fragment.RegisterFragment"
        android:label="RegisterFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_register">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_registerFragment_to_loginFragment2"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/accountOptionsFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/accountOptionsFragment"
        android:name="com.example.go.ui.fragment.AccountOptionsFragment"
        android:label="AccountOptionsFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_account_options">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_accountOptionsFragment_to_loginFragment"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_accountOptionsFragment_to_registerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/registerFragment" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

**here's the way I move for all of the fragments**

```
 binding.buttonStart.setOnClickListener {

            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_introdcutionFragment_to_accountOptionsFragment)

        }
```

the rest is default like  didn't added code in the activity
I cant think of what code you might need to see in my project (if I know what part of the code is wrong ...) so if you need to see a file leave a comment
thx.